# Sort a matrix of points into row column order

Tags: matlab, matrix, grid-layout

I have a matrix of x,y coordinates. The coordinates came from identifying blobs that are in row, column order. The locations of the blobs vary a bit because of distortion of the image and some other factors. The locations are also not in any particular order. The grid of points could also be rotated a few degrees. If you were to draw a line from a row or column of these points the line may curve a bit. The example here is simplified. In real life I may have a grid that numbers up to 40,000 points.

Here is a simplified version:
[image: grid of points]

I need to sort that "cloud" of data into a matrix that is in either row, column order or column, row order.

1) Is there a matlab function that may do this?

2) If not any ideas would be appreciated.

*EDIT*
Here is a small example with a small data set. The data is x,y data points and as you can see, they are spaced on a grid.

Unsorted:
x   y
126.5833333 1052.129845
125.9961905 1200.893333
125.8657845 1126.151229
202.5411765 1052.119608
128.4703704 976.0331384
201.5103189 1126.928705
201.1538462 1201.41651
202.907197  976.4185606

I need to order them like this:
x   y
128.4703704 976.0331384
126.5833333 1052.129845
125.8657845 1126.151229
125.9961905 1200.893333
202.907197  976.4185606
202.5411765 1052.119608
201.5103189 1126.928705
201.1538462 1201.41651

Comment: Can you give a small example of input data and desired output data? It's not clear to me what you exactly want to do.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - can you provide some actual data?